# Handler refrence always leads back to first rendered component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component, where i have instances of a `SingleFileUpload` component, which serves to upload a different type of file for each component.

```js
  <SingleFileUpload 
           keyProp={"standardFileName"}
           title={"Standard File"}
           buttonText={"Upload Standard file"}
           isSingleFile={false} 
           handleFile={this.onChangeHandler} 
           submitSuccess={submitSuccess} 
           name={standardFileName} 
           deleteFileHandler={this.deleteStandardFileHandler}
           file={standardFile}/>
          < br/>
          <SingleFileUpload 
          keyProp={"entitlementFileName"}
          title={"Entitlement File"}
          buttonText={"Upload Entitlement file"}
          isSingleFile={false}
          handleFile={this.onChangeHandler} 
          submitSuccess={submitSuccess} 
          name={entitlementFileName} 
          deleteFileHandler={this.deleteEntitlementFileHandler}
          file={entitlementFile}/>
```

each of these are used with a generic handler for setting the actual file, and aditionally a name for the file

```
onChangeHandler = (e, keyProp) =>{
console.log('keyprop is', keyProp)
e.preventDefault()
const file = keyProp.split('Name')[0];
const fileName = keyProp;
if(e.target.files[0].name.split('.')[1] !== 'xlsx'){
  return alert('Please only upload Excel files')
 }
  this.setState({
    [file]: e.target.files[0],
    [fileName]: e.target.files[0].name
  }, () => console.log(this.state))
};
```

the problem is, that whenever the callback is used within any `SingleFileUpload`  it always passese the props of the first rendered component

```
  /*inside SingleFileUpload */
    <Button variant="contained" component="span" className={"button"} onChange=
{(e) => {handleFile(e, keyProp), console.log('handler called with ', keyProp  /* this always logs whatever prpops are passed to the first component */)}} style={{margin: '10px'}}>
           <input
           style={{display: 'none'}}
       accept=".xlsx"
       className={"input"}
       id="contained-button-file"
       type="file"
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same `id` (`id="contained-button-file"`) for the file input